# What should I do if I see a late duplicate answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

When I visit recently-active but old questions, I often find that the activity consists of a new answer which duplicates, in briefer form, a long-existing answer. Such answers are often from new users and are generally reasonably accurate, but entirely duplicative of another answer long since posted.

What should I do in this case, as a <10k user?

Should I downvote it? Should I flag it? Should I comment on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore it. Having multiple answers on a question is not a bug, it's a feature. That someone came later with an answer that doesn't add anything is not a problem - it will simply go to the bottom of the pile.

If it is not as good as existing answers, but is still correct, it does not deserve an upvote or a downvote.

If you feel that the poster needs to be educated about such matters, comment about it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually flag those types of things -- with an explanation of why I think it should be removed.

As long as you are not annoying the mods too much with flags on old answers, it should be fine.

I would not downvote, because that would imply the answer is wrong, which it is not.

Comment: Downvotes also mean "is not useful".